# Invalid Characters in Path

Tags: c#

```
if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(message).ToLower() == "mp4")
```

The above statement throws an argument exception that is baffling me as the error "Invalid Characters in Path" seems wrong in the context that message is equal to this:

```
string message = @"D:\Cases\Case 0\Records\Videos\VID_2014_1222163200_0.MP4"
```

I can't seem to find the invalid character!

```
BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message))
```

Will return this:

12/23/2014-4:06:14 PM: ERROR: 44-00-3A-00-5C-00-43-00-61-00-73-00-65-00-73-00-5C-00-43-00-61-00-73-00-65-00-20-00-30-00-5C-00-52-00-65-00-63-00-6F-00-72-00-64-00-73-00-5C-00-56-00-69-00-64-00-65-00-6F-00-73-00-5C-00-56-00-49-00-44-00-5F-00-32-00-30-00-31-00-34-00-5F-00-31-00-32-00-32-00-32-00-31-00-36-00-33-00-32-00-30-00-30-00-5F-00-30-00-2E-00-4D-00-50-00-34-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00

Comment: Aside, I'd recommend using string.Equals instead of calling `ToLower` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: you need a "." in your comparison - however the provided code compiles without error, so you must not be providing all necessary code to reproduce the issue. https://dotnetfiddle.net/wMUKrm

Comment: The code works on my machine without the error message.

Comment: message is not actually a field, but a parameter in a message pipe that is received on the server end, I did it the way above to avoid writing the entire message pipe. If I MessageBox.Show the parameter I get the literal string above.

Comment: @bl4kh4k Perhaps a different section of code is throwing this then?

Comment: Which could be the "sense" of an Extension without "." ? in which O.S. could it have sense ? I guess not in Windows

Comment: I commented out all code within that routine except for the if statement alone. Still Invalid characters in path. :(

Comment: @bl4kh4k Perhaps there is a `\0` in there. `MessageBox.Show` treats its input as null terminated. Use `BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s))` and post the result.

Comment: @bl4kh4k - You almost certainly have some non-printable characters which you're not seeing/noticing in the messagebox but are in the string - see my answer below for example of using Trim()

Comment: `Your If Statement will never execute` because you need to change it to the following first `if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(message).ToLower() == ".mp4")` extension returns `.` btw + the chars to the right of the `.` I do not get errors so perhaps ypu need to show all relevant code... your path raises Zero errors as well `string message = @"D:\Cases\Case 0\Records\Videos\VID_2014_1222163200_0.MP4";`

Comment: I updated the question with the BitConverter response.

Comment: The problem is that your code that creates the `message` string from the data buffer received from the pipe is converting the entire buffer rather than just the bytes that were read. You need to show us how `message` is constructed.

Comment: Are you checking the return value of `stream.Read`? It tells you how many bytes were actually read, which can be smaller than the number of requested bytes.

Comment: It was literally the /0's at the end... messagebox was filtering those out.

Comment: Yes, and those 0 bytes at the end are the result of your code incorrectly using the entire buffer to construct the `message`, rather than just the bytes that were read.

Answer (score 1):

There's no exception problem with the code as copied from your question.

Sometimes hard-to-spot invalid characters in string literals come from cutting and pasting from things like web browsers into code.  If I were you, I would re-type the literal by hand.

The function throwing this exception has a test which looks like this:

```
if (c == '\"' || c == '<' || c == '>' || c == '|' || c < 32)
```

Knowing this might give you some clue what's wrong.

Update:

Following the comments which reveal that the original code example is not reflective of the application, I'd suggest you add a `.Trim()` call:

```
if (Path.GetExtension(message.Trim()).Equals(".mp4",
                           StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

(I've also fixed the .mp4 string and the comparison for you.)

Answer (score 1):

Use this single line of code and it should return to you the index number of the invalid character (0-based). If it returns anything `< 0`, then there are no invalid characters in your path.

```
int ndx = message.IndexOfAny(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
```